# Mongo collection has no .find method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have a database on MongoLab. It has several collections. All but one work. One collection is called "selectopts". It has two documents. I can clearly see these two documents.

In my express code I have...

```
var db = require('mongojs');
db.connect('mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@ds053xxx.mongolab.com:53xxx/rednecks',['selectopts']);


exports.selects = function (req, res) {
    db.selectopts.find(function (err, s) {
        if (err) return;
        res.json(s);
    });
};
```

It always errors at `db.selectopts.find...`, *TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined*. This exact same stupid simple code works fine for four other collections. Why is just this one collection not coming back from MongoLab?

I'm so completely stumped.

**EDIT...**

Tried db.collection('selectopts').find(... and got this error...

[image]

**EDIT again...**

Here are the two docs in the selectopts collection on MongoLab. Do you see some problem with the docs?...

[image]

**EDIT x 3...**

This is the correct/working mongo connection setup code...

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs.connect(
    'xxx:xxx@ds053xxx.mongolab.com:53xxx/rednecks',
);
```

See the main difference? (SMFH) :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when I post at SO I don't receive the exact actual answer from any one reply, but somehow you guys *always steer me toward the answer*. In this case, it was programmer stupidity. My code at the top of the route js file is wrong. You can see it wrong at the top of this post. I edited and added the correct syntax, which magically got everything working.

To eliminate this type of repetition/syntax/non-DRY bungling, I moved the mongo connection lines into a separate database.js file and require it at the top of the route files. Genius huh?!? :-D

"Thank you" x 100 for all your replies! You always get me back on track :-)

Answer (score 0):

Connect using the following style:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@ds053xxx.mongolab.com:53xxx/rednecks', 
    {auto_reconnect: true}, 
    function(e, database)
{
  db = database;
});


exports.selects = function (req, res) {
    db.selectopts.find(function (err, s) {
        if (err) return;
        res.json(s);
    });
};
```